# SQL Server : each month for the rows and the years for the columns

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am a trying to neatly separate data by year, I have the following query that accomplishes this, however, the date column (YYYYMM) shows every month of every year. So each annual column is zeros for most rows except the ones for its respective year.

```
SELECT      
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(l.Date), MONTH(l.Date), 01) AS YYYYMM,
    SUM(CASE WHEN l.State ='UT' AND YEAR(l.Date) = '2018' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'UT - 2018',
    SUM(CASE WHEN l.State ='UT' AND YEAR(l.Date) = '2019' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'UT - 2019',
    SUM(CASE WHEN l.State ='UT' AND YEAR(l.Date) = '2020' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'UT - 2020',
    SUM(CASE WHEN l.State ='AZ' AND YEAR(l.Date) = '2018' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'AZ - 2018',
    SUM(CASE WHEN l.State  ='AZ' AND YEAR(l.Date) = '2019' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'AZ - 2019',
    SUM(CASE WHEN l.State ='AZ' AND YEAR(l.Date) = '2020' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'AZ - 2020',
    SUM(CASE WHEN l.State ='NV' AND YEAR(l.Date) = '2020' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'NV - 2020'
FROM
    dbo.list AS l,
    dbo.StatusLogs AS sl
WHERE
    sl.ListId = l.Id
GROUP BY    
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(l.Date), MONTH(l.Date), 01)
ORDER BY    
    DATEFROMPARTS(YEAR(l.Date), MONTH(l.Date), 01)
```

What I am trying to do is to just have 12 rows (1 row for each month). Like this:

```
MM       UT - 2018     ....     NV - 2020
Jan        10                     5
Feb        5                      8
...
Dec        6                      7
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Learn to use proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.

Then, the fix is to just change the `GROUP BY` and `SELECT`:

```
 SELECT MONTH(l.Date) AS month,
        SUM(CASE WHEN l.State ='UT' AND YEAR(l.Date) = 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [UT - 2018],
        SUM(CASE WHEN l.State ='UT' AND YEAR(l.Date) = 2019 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [UT - 2019],
        SUM(CASE WHEN l.State ='UT' AND YEAR(l.Date) = 2020 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [UT - 2020],
        SUM(CASE WHEN l.State ='AZ' AND YEAR(l.Date) = 2018 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [AZ - 2018],
        SUM(CASE WHEN l.State  ='AZ' AND YEAR(l.Date) = 2019 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [AZ - 2019],
        SUM(CASE WHEN l.State ='AZ' AND YEAR(l.Date) = 2020 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [AZ - 2020],
        SUM(CASE WHEN l.State ='NV' AND YEAR(l.Date) = 2020 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS [NV - 2020]
 FROM dbo.list l JOIN
      dbo.StatusLogs sl
      ON sl.ListId = l.Id
 GROUP BY MONTH(l.Date)
 ORDER BY MONTH(l.Date);
```

I also removed a bunch of single quotes.  Single quotes should be used only for date and string constants.  `YEAR()` returns a number, so the comparison should be a number.  Column aliases should really not need to be escaped, but if you have non-conforming names, then use square braces.  Single quotes confuses the column name with a value.

Comment: Beautiful! Thank you so much