# Display mutliple data in one row for same date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to display same dates as row but data as columns.

Here are the details

My query:

```
SELECT
       [commodity]
      ,[ordinal]
      ,[units]
      ,[valid]
      ,[date]
      ,[hub]
      ,[period]
      ,[mid]
      ,[timebase]

FROM [PETL].[dbo].[Historical_Prices]
  WHERE commodity = 'Gas'
  AND source = 'ICE'
  AND date >= '2017-01-01'
  AND hub = 'TTF'

ORDER BY CONVERT(date, date, 105) DESC
```

This query returns this result:

```
commodity   ordinal units   valid   date                    hub period  mid     timebase
Gas         97      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-21 00:00:00.000 TTF Apr20   16.0440  Month
Gas         98      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-21 00:00:00.000 TTF May20   16.1160  Month
Gas         99      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-21 00:00:00.000 TTF Jun20   16.2060  Month
Gas         37      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-24 00:00:00.000 TTF Apr20   15.5350  Month
Gas         38      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-24 00:00:00.000 TTF May20   15.4600  Month
Gas         39      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-24 00:00:00.000 TTF Jun20   15.5000  Month
Gas         40      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-24 00:00:00.000 TTF Jul20   15.2600  Month
Gas         41      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-24 00:00:00.000 TTF Aug20   15.0900  Month
Gas         42      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-24 00:00:00.000 TTF Sep20   14.6950  Month
Gas         43      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-24 00:00:00.000 TTF Oct20   15.3150  Month
Gas         49      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-29 00:00:00.000 TTF APR20   15.2910  Month
Gas         50      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-29 00:00:00.000 TTF May20   15.2910  Month
Gas         51      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-29 00:00:00.000 TTF Jun20   15.4310  Month
Gas         52      EUR/MWh   Y     2017-03-29 00:00:00.000 TTF Jul20   15.4460  Month
```

Expected output format:

```
Month            APR-20     May-20    Jun-20
--------------------------------------------------------------
21/03/2017      16.0440     16.1160    16.2060
24/03/2017      15.5350     15.4600    15.5000
29/03/2017      15.2910     15.2910    15.4310
```

I have multiple Dates, not just the three shown in the sample.

How can I get my expected output? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is your column `date` *really* a string based data type?

Comment: As for what you are asking, this is known as pivoting, or conditional aggregation. There are *plenty* of examples out there for this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I make "month" columns in Sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2296628/how-can-i-make-month-columns-in-sql)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Server : each month for the rows and the years for the columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62198014/sql-server-each-month-for-the-rows-and-the-years-for-the-columns)

Comment: pivot is available at sqlserver